# How to convert MySQL query to PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to get data from database using Codeigniter as framework.

I was able to come up with SQL query for desired result, but since I am not familiar with Codeigniter DB syntax, I am having a trouble. Below is the query that I want to execute. How do I do this in php?

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM
    (SELECT A.*
    FROM DriversInfo as A, InvoiceQueue as B
    WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime
    AND B.Error <> 1
    GROUP BY A.CreateTime
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT A.*
    FROM DriversInfo as A, OrderInfo as B
    WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverKey
    AND B.Invoice <> '0') as A
LEFT JOIN DriversDoc as B
on A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime
WHERE B.DriversLicense is null
OR B.CarRegistration is null
OR B.BizCertificate is null
OR B.Insurance is null;
```

Comment: If in phpmyadmin, then you can create there.

Comment: for getting query result in codeigniter: $query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY")->result_array();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT A.*, B.* FROM (SELECT A.* FROM DriversInfo as A, InvoiceQueue as B WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime AND B.Error <> 1 GROUP BY A.CreateTime UNION  SELECT DISTINCT A.* FROM DriversInfo as A, OrderInfo as B  WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverKey  AND B.Invoice <> '0') as A LEFT JOIN DriversDoc as B on A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime WHERE B.DriversLicense is null OR B.CarRegistration is null OR B.BizCertificate is null OR B.Insurance is null;");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$qry = "SELECT A.*, B.*
    FROM
    (SELECT A.*
    FROM DriversInfo as A, InvoiceQueue as B
    WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime
    AND B.Error <> 1
    GROUP BY A.CreateTime
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT A.*
    FROM DriversInfo as A, OrderInfo as B
    WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverKey
    AND B.Invoice <> '0') as A
    LEFT JOIN DriversDoc as B
    on A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime
    WHERE B.DriversLicense is null
    OR B.CarRegistration is null
    OR B.BizCertificate is null
    OR B.Insurance is null;";

$query = $this->db->query($qry);

$result = $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM
    (SELECT A.*
    FROM DriversInfo as A, InvoiceQueue as B
    WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime
    AND B.Error <> 1
    GROUP BY A.CreateTime
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT A.*
    FROM DriversInfo as A, OrderInfo as B
    WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverKey
    AND B.Invoice <> '0') as A
LEFT JOIN DriversDoc as B
on A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime
WHERE B.DriversLicense is null
OR B.CarRegistration is null
OR B.BizCertificate is null
OR B.Insurance is null";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //displaying row
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to just use `mysqli_query()` function with connection variable.

```
<?php

    $sql = "YOUR QUERY";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //Access like $row["id"]
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

IF u want to run this query in codeigniter way, then try this

```
$this->db->select('A.*, B.*')
$this->db->from('(SELECT A.*
    FROM DriversInfo as A, InvoiceQueue as B
    WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime
    AND B.Error <> 1
    GROUP BY A.CreateTime
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
    FROM DriversInfo as A, OrderInfo as B WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverKey AND B.Invoice <> '0') as A')

$this->db->join('DriversDoc', 'A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime ', 'left');
$this->db->where('B.DriversLicense', null);
$this->db->or_where('B.CarRegistration', null);
$this->db->or_where('B.BizCertificate', null);
$this->db->or_where('B.Insurance', null);
$this->db->get();
```

U can also try like this.

```
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM
    (SELECT A.*
    FROM DriversInfo as A, InvoiceQueue as B
    WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime
    AND B.Error <> 1
    GROUP BY A.CreateTime
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT A.*
    FROM DriversInfo as A, OrderInfo as B
    WHERE A.CreateTime = B.DriverKey
    AND B.Invoice <> '0') as A
LEFT JOIN DriversDoc as B
on A.CreateTime = B.DriverCreateTime
WHERE B.DriversLicense is null
OR B.CarRegistration is null
OR B.BizCertificate is null
OR B.Insurance is null;');
        echo print_r($query->result());
```

For more Information You can check here
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 1):

I've being working with CI since 2013. Below are the basic structures to work with database in CodeIgniter. Subqueries and `UNION` are not supported so you need to either do a `SELECT` in both databases and then do `$query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2);` or write your own clause using union.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.id = table1.id'); //same as JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.id = table1.id', 'left'); //produces a LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
$this->db->where('column1', 'data');  //same as WHERE column1 = 'data'
$this->db->where("colum1 = 'data' OR column2 = 'data2'"); // you can write you own clause
$this->db->like('title', 'match'); //same as WHERE title LIKE '%match%'
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before'); //same as WHERE title LIKE '%match'
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after'); //same as WHERE title LIKE 'match%'
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both'); //same as WHERE title LIKE '%match%'
$this->db->group_by("title"); 
$this->db->order_by('title', 'ASC');


$query = $this->db->get();
```

For more info: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html